# Unable to instantiate a Struct with 'self' in one of the variables

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am trying to create a struct that contains two variables so that I can have access to it in the same class. I am unable to get the frame of the current view controller by declaring 'self' when instantiating this struct.

```
class aviewController: UIViewController{

struct loadingOverlay {
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView
    var overlay: UIView
}

// INSTANTIATE

let loadingDisplay = loadingOverlay.init(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView.init(), overlay: UIView.init(frame: self)) // I am trying to type 'self.view.frame'.  But 'self' is not recognised???

}
```

The instance of the struct would be used to show and hide an overlay to the current UIViewController:

```
// SHOW OVERLAY WITH LOADING CIRCLE
func showLoadingCircle(activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView, overlayView: UIView){

    activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicatorView.color = .gray
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    overlayView.alpha = 0.5
    overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
}
```

In the above function, I need access to a 'activityIndicatorView' and 'overlayView'.

Comment: Is this instantiated inside a view controller?

Comment: Where is this code being called? `self` only makes sense in the context of an instance method, where there is actually an instance for `self` to refer to.

Comment: @Chris .yes. Within a UIViewController

Comment: Is it inside a view controller method, like `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: can you post the code of your class where the statement is called?

Comment: @Chris I would like to make use of the struct within a function.  The instance of the struct would act a a global variable.  I don't have to use a struct.  if you have an alternative solution i am open to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that `self` is initiated first before referring to it in `self.view.frame`. So put the formula for `loadingDisplay` in `viewDidLoad()` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    struct LoadingOverlay {
        var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView
        var overlay: UIView
    }

    //If you're sure that once the loader is initiated it will never be nil, then declare it as an implicitly unwrapped property
    var loadingDisplay: LoadingOverlay!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadingDisplay = LoadingOverlay.init(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView.init(), overlay: UIView.init(frame: self.view.frame))
    }
}
```

`viewDidLoad()` is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. So you'll be sure that `self` is not nil.

Another way to initialize your properties safely is do so in the initializer of your class:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //It is essential to start with this line to be able to refer to self later
    loadingDisplay = LoadingOverlay.init(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView.init(), overlay: UIView.init(frame: self.view.frame))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

A third way is to make this property a computed property:

```
var loadingDisplay: LoadingOverlay {
    return LoadingOverlay.init(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView.init(), overlay: UIView.init(frame: self.view.frame))}
```

(P.S: It is a naming convention in Swift to have the first letter uppercased for Class and Struct names. Have a look [here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) to write Swift with style.)

Comment: Good answer. Good to clarify that `self` must exist first, and the use of implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use **lazy**

```
lazy var loadingDisplay = loadingOverlay(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView(), overlay: UIView(frame: self.view.frame))
```

Comment: Should the last bit be: `(frame: self.view.frame)`